# Check the presence of an environment variable as a prerequisite to a WiX Installer

Tags: xml, wix, windows-installer

I'm working on my first WiX based installer, and I need to ensure that a particular environment variable is NOT set prior to installing.  This is to ensure that another instance of the client I'm installing isn't already installed under a different, path (it does NOT use the same GUIDs as I am using.)

This client also does not set any registry keys, nor does it have a known path to check.

Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT:
So I've tried two different approaches, and neither has worked.

1st approach (with approach 2 commented out.)  I have this XML just inside the `<Product>` element.

`<?ifdef env.MY_VAR ?>`

`<Condition Message="MY_VAR already defined.">0</Condition>`

`<?endif?>`

Unfortunately, this seems to always evaluate to true, whether %MY_VAR% is set or not, and the message is displayed, and the installer exits gracefully (as I want it to.)

2nd approach. (With approach 1 commented out,) I have this XML just inside the `<Product>` element.
`<Condition Message="Error: MY_VAR environment variable already set."><![CDATA[MYVAR <> ""]]></Condition>`

I also define a `<CustomAction>` inside a `<Fragment>` referenced in the Product, as such:
`<CustomAction Id="GetMyVar" Property="MYVAR" Value="[%MY_VAR]" />`

with that `<CustomAction>` being sequenced inside an `<InstallExecuteSequence>` element as such:
`<Custom Action="GetTNSAdmin" After="LaunchConditions" />`

This also results in the same "always evaluate to true" behavior I've seen in the first approach.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that Wix is declarative. You're attempting to combine procedural code with Wix's declarative nature. *You're gonna have a bad time.*

Your first approach failed because ifdef is a compile-time directive much like the C/C++ preprocessor's ifdef. It won't help you at runtime.

Not sure what you're 2nd approach is trying to do with the CDATA block. You're close though:

```
<Condition Message="An important environment variable is already defined.">
NOT %IMPORTANT_ENV_VAR
</Condition>
```

As PhilDW said, you need to put a % before the environment variable and add the NOT condition. Remember that the message is displayed if the condition is **FALSE**.

Read about [launch conditions](http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/02/10/from-msi-to-wix-part-3.aspx) here.

Answer (score 1):

A launch condition is built from these conditional statements:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012(v=vs.85).aspx

so it looks like a condition of NOT %ENVNAME should work.

You could use a component guid from that other install in a ComponentSearch:

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/componentsearch.html

These don't care about path - it'll just tell you if that component guid is installed.

Comment: Thanks PhilDW.  I've updated my original post with a bit more information.  I believe my "2nd approach," is similar to what you suggested, but it's not behaving as expected.  Am I missing something?